# how can i display the function which has no asterisked at the end?

Tags: r

```
methods(print)
omitted many outputs
[175] print.vignette*  print.warnings   print.xgettext*                              
[178] print.xngettext*  print.xtabs*                                 

 Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

how can i get the function on print which has no asteriske  at the end ?
`print.warnings` should be displayed ,`print.xtabs*`  should not be displayed.

```
 methods(print)->x
 x[grep("^//*",x)]
 x[grep("^*",x)]
```

it is failure.

Comment: `grep("*", as.character(methods(print)), fixed=T, invert=T, value=T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterisks aren't really part of the string (so they won't be detected by applying `grep` to the strings, even if you get the regular expression incantation right), they're appended by the `print.MethodsFunction` method.  Maybe this will do what you want:

```
methods(print)->x
vis <- attr(x,"info")[,"visible"]
x[!vis]
x[vis]
```

(I figured this out by looking at the output of `str(x)`)